# can't understand centroid and Distance formula in this code

Tags: python, matlab

I'm struggling to understand the normalisation process of the 8 point algorithm. I am referring [this code in MATLAB](https://github.com/DzReal/8-point-algorithm-MATLAB/blob/master/getNormMat2d.m) which I'm not able to run since I don't have matlab.

```
function Nmatrix = getNormMat2d(x)

Nmatrix - the normalization matrix
%       x - input data, dim: 3xN

% Get the centroid
centroid = mean(x, 2);
% Compute the distance to the centroid
dist = sqrt(sum((x - repmat(centroid, 1, size(x, 2))) .^ 2, 1));
% Get the mean distance
mean_dist = mean(dist);
% Craft normalization matrix
Nmatrix = [sqrt(2) / mean_dist, 0, -sqrt(2) / mean_dist * centroid(1);...
           0, sqrt(2) / mean_dist, -sqrt(2) / mean_dist * centroid(2);...
           0, 0, 1];

end
```

I'm trying to code this in Python. But I don't understand a few things :

Aren't centroids supposed to be like :

```
#dummy points 
x1 = np.array([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 30, 20, 40])
y1 =  np.array([12, 34, 56, 78, 89, 45, 90, 29])
# did the following to give it the shape the matlab function expects
first=np.stack((x1,y1),axis = 1) 
ones=np.ones((8,1))
first = np.concatenate((first,ones),axis = 1)
p1 = np.ndarray.transpose(first)
#centroid
centroid_x = np.mean(p1[0,:])
centroid_y = np.mean(p1[1,:])
```

I dont understand why they used `centroid = mean(x, 2);`. Apart from that, the line `dist = sqrt(sum((x - repmat(centroid, 1, size(x, 2))) .^ 2, 1));` isn't going in my head very well.

Please help me understand this

About the algorithm :

We need to get a transformation matrix (translation and scaling) such that the new coordinate system has it's origin at the centroid, and after the translation the coordinates are uniformly scaled so that the mean distance from the origin to a point equals $sqrt(2)$

Comment: Just as a note you don't even need the `repmat(centroid, 1, size(x, 2))`, you can just do `centroid` (at least in more current versions of Matlab, maybe not in older versions(?))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's go through this

```
centroid = mean(x, 2);
```

takes the mean along rows, so `x` is 3 rows and N columns. This means that `centroid` is a 3x1 vector `[xC ; yC ; zC]`

```
dist = sqrt(sum((x - repmat(centroid, 1, size(x, 2))) .^ 2, 1));
```

Let's go through this outside to inside

```
repmat(centroid, 1, size(x, 2))
```

makes a matrix with N copies of `centroid`. Then the `-` takes the difference between the point and the centroid, giving a 3xN matrix. The `.^2` just squares each of the elements for the 3xN matrix. The `sum( ... , 1 )` adds along the row (i.e. adding the x-, y-, and z-components together). Then the `sqrt` takes the square root.

So running your python example through the Matlab code

```
x1 = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 30, 20, 40];
y1 = [12, 34, 56, 78, 89, 45, 90, 29];
x = [ x1 ; y1 ];
centroid = mean(x, 2);
dist = sqrt(sum((x - repmat(centroid, 1, size(x, 2))) .^ 2, 1));
dist'

ans =

      45.1506159980127
      21.0731612483747
      4.19262745781211
      27.5513724703507
      42.1939346944558
      11.0602045641118
      39.3837291911266
      25.4033093316599
```

And the equivalent python

```
x1 = np.array([20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 30, 20, 40])
y1 =  np.array([12, 34, 56, 78, 89, 45, 90, 29])
x = np.column_stack((x1,y1))
centroid = np.mean( np.transpose( x ) )
dist = [ np.sqrt( np.sum( np.square( v - centroid ) ) ) for v in x ]
dist
[45.1506159980127, 21.073161248374674, 4.192627457812105, 27.551372470350728, 42.19393469445579, 11.060204564111823, 39.38372919112663, 25.40330933165992]
```